# Assassin Mindbender

Tags: dnd-3.5e, assassin

How can a character that can only cast assassin spells and can't employ invocations meet the requirements for mindbender?

Edit: Is there anything in RAW that states that UMD, and a scroll of Charm Person would not meet the Prereq?

Comment: Well, originally it was just for telepathy, but, yes, it is for Mindsight.

Comment: In that case, it's totally okay to ask a (new) question like *What's the least resource-intensive way for a this PC to take the feat Mindsight?* then provide details about that PC and the resources available in the campaign. So you know, the site likes those kinds of specific questions *a lot* because they help the asker directly and immediately *and* offer contributors an opportunity to flex within a controlled environment rather than speculate as to what the environment might be.

Comment: As @HeyICanChan notes, other ways of qualifying for Mindsight is a new, separate question; leave this one as it is. You can ask about qualifying with scrolls separately, too. One question per Question—it will get you better answers, sooner, and it will help us keep the site organized. Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what the environment is as of yet, I am starting a game next week as a 3rd level character, but I am trying to get a strategic overview of what I want the character to be around 20th lvl. The DM is being very secretive about what the world is.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Instead, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in order revisions can view the revision history.

Comment: The DM won't even tell you what material is allowed in the campaign? Oof. Good luck! I recommend being prepared with several radically different characters and ideas for several more just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Charm person* as assassin spell

Actually getting *charm person* as an assassin spell is a bit tricky. Arcane Disciple, a feat from *Complete Divine*, can add the spells of a domain to your arcane spell list—Charm, Fey, Lust, Renewal, Seduction, and Temptation all get it (though it’s bizarrely a 2nd-level spell for the Fey domain). However, they’ll use Wisdom instead of Intelligence, which sucks.

#### *Charm person* as spell-like ability

*Complete Mage* has the Fey Presence feat, which grants a 6th-level non-lawful character the ability to cast *charm person* as a spell-like ability once per day (also *deep slumber* and *disguise self*, each also once per day). Fey Presence also requires Fey Heritage, unfortunately, which is a rather-weak feat.

The assassin class itself can meet the arcane caster level 5th requirement. Nothing says that the caster level requirement has to be met for *charm* itself—which is good because while Fey Presence gives its SLAs a caster level equal to your character level, it isn’t an *arcane* caster level. Practiced Spellcaster (assassin) can be taken to improve your assassin caster level to 5th earlier, if you like, though since Fey Presence requires 6th it won’t save you very much.

#### *Charm* invocation

Simply unavailable to anyone who isn’t a dragonfire adept or warlock. Actually, I think there are some fiends that get invocations for some weird reason, but I don’t think they’re playable and even if they were, they are unlikely to be a good solution.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think that a Magic Item would be able to get past a Class Prereq, otherwise just being an arcane caster would "Allow" me to cast the spell with a scroll.

Comment: @CrimRei It gets *really* debatable what counts, but generally speaking, items can qualify. A scroll probably wouldn’t, because it’s not using one of your spell slots—there’s general consensus that this is what prerequisites are looking for, though the rules never spell it out. But some of the things HeyICanChan mentioned allow you to use your spell slots to cast spells you ordinarily couldn’t—that might well be fair game.

Comment: @CrimRei It's a legalistic thing but still a thing: The requirement is that the prospective mindbender be "[a]ble to cast *charm person*" rather than, for instance, "[a]ble to cast 4th-level arcane spells" like the fatespinner or whatever. If the creature can meet all of the mindbender's *other* requirements, being able to cast *charm person* when the class is entered *via* a magic item is cake. (*Full Disclosure:* I find many prestige class requirements distasteful: being forced to take (and sometimes keep!) crap now for shiny later is, in my opinion, a terrible way to balance a game.)

Comment: Absolutely agree with @HeyICanChan there. The entire concept of prestige classes, at least as presented in 3.5e (or Pathfinder) is suspect. 4e’s paragon paths and epic destinies implemented the same concept far better.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, I agree. Alot of the Feat Reqs are completely BS in my opinion as they have little or nothing to do with the class.